# Add additional result statement to jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following script which is working nicely to hide a DIV when its child is empty:

```
jQuery(".field-items").filter(function() {
      return !$.trim(this.innerHTML);
   }).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
```

If that same DIV is empty from above I also want to hide another DIV on the same page. It's not a parent.

How can I add the following code to the above code? So that both occur when that specific DIV is empty?

```
$('#survey-monkey-title').hide();
```

Comment: Don't use `.parent().parent()` - use `.closest()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var $empty = jQuery(".field-items").filter(function() {
    return !$.trim(this.innerHTML);
});
if ($empty.length) {
    $empty.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().hide();
    $('#survey-monkey-title').hide();
}
```

I'd also like to give Brian Giaz his *propers* for utilizing `.add()` below:

```
$empty.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().add('#survey-monkey-title').hide();
```

Comment: Sure. It would be much, much cleaner if you have a class or ID by which to refer to the first element you want hidden. So if you had:
  `<div class='superParent'><div><div><div><div><div><div>test for empty</div></div></div></div></div></div></div>`
you could just refer to it as `$empty.closest('.superParent').hide();` instead of chaining 7 calls to `.parent()`.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do have an ID that I can reference and it cleaned things up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) function to add additional elements to the jquery object:

```
$('#elem').parent().add('#otherElem').hide();
```

for example.

Comment: Not sure why there are two downvotes on a correct answer... but whatever.

Comment: Maybe those peeps don't know what `.add()` does, or they expect more specific answers here. It's alright. I'd upvote you twice if I could -- to return balance to the force.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already got it working, but consider updating the stringed parent() calls to just a single parentUntil function.

```
var $empty = jQuery(".field-items").filter(function() {
    return !$.trim(this.innerHTML);
});
if ($empty.length) {
    $empty.parentsUntil('.someSelector').hide();
    $('#survey-monkey-title').hide();
}
```